# SQL query to sum column and group by interval within a range, which includes every interval in that range

Tags: sql, group-by

Given a table (SomeTable):

```
Id  Count   TimeStamp
1   7047    2014-06-12 16:09:49.000
2   4577    2014-06-12 16:09:52.000
3   3517    2014-06-12 16:09:54.003
4   6078    2014-06-12 16:09:56.000
5   3619    2014-06-12 16:09:58.000
6   6652    2014-06-12 16:10:00.000
7   4200    2014-06-12 16:10:02.000
8   3852    2014-06-12 16:10:04.000
```

I need to write a query that returns and sums all activity (count) within the last 60 minutes (grouped by minute) which includes a value for each interval (minute) regardless.

```
Id  Count   TimeStamp
1   2342342 2014-06-12 16:09:00.000
2   343435  2014-06-12 16:10:00.000
3   0       2014-06-12 16:11:00.000
...
```

I have the following

```
select dateadd(minute, 1+datediff(minute, 0, [TimeStamp]), 0) as [sdfTimeStamp],
       sum([Count]) as [sfCount]
from [ProcessCounts]
group by dateadd(minute, 1+datediff(minute, 0, [TimeStamp]), 0)
```

It's returning results as follows:

```
2014-06-12 16:10:00.000     24838
2014-06-12 16:11:00.000     19437
2014-06-12 16:21:00.000     45647
2014-06-12 16:23:00.000     61138
```

As you can see this query doesn't report on all the intervals (minutes), it the doesn't get latest 60 minutes and doesn't return exactly 60 rows

### Update

I guess I can live with out trying get a value for every interval (even when no data exists), however I'd still be interested to see a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select all data from the past 60 minutes (using `DateDiff`) and `GROUP BY` hour & minute using `datepart`

```
SELECT 
    datepart(hour,TimeStamp) hour,
    datepart(minute, TimeStamp) minute,
    SUM(count)
FROM
SomeTable t1
WHERE DateDiff(MINUTE,TimeStamp,GetDate()) <= 60
GROUP BY datepart(minute, TimeStamp), datepart(hour,TimeStamp)
```

For missing intervals the query below creates a derived table containing each of the past 60 minutes and left joins that table to the results from the query above.

```
WITH q AS
(
    SELECT  1 AS num
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  num + 1
    FROM    q
    WHERE   num < 60
)

SELECT 
    datepart(minute, t1.TimeStamp) minute, 
    datepart(hour,t1.TimeStamp) hour,
    COALESCE(t2.total_count,0) total_count
FROM (SELECT dateadd(MINUTE,-num,getdate()) TimeStamp FROM q) t1
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
        datepart(hour,TimeStamp) hour,
        datepart(minute, TimeStamp) minute,
        SUM(count) total_count
    FROM SomeTable t1
    WHERE DateDiff(MINUTE,TimeStamp,GetDate()) < 60
    GROUP BY datepart(minute, TimeStamp), datepart(hour,TimeStamp)
) t2 ON t2.hour = datepart(hour, t1.TimeStamp) 
     AND t2.minute = datepart(hour, t1.TimeStamp)
```

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to include missing intervals, ie intervals which are not in the table, ie if there was no activity in the last 3 minutes, it would have 0 for those intervals

Comment: The last hour is meant to be minute, other that it worked perfectly, plus your other edits, fix that and the points are yours